# Why ionic set the grid `.col` `display:block` and `width: 100%` properties?

Tags: css, ionic-framework, sass, flexbox

when I read the ionic's `_grid.scss` source code.
I found this style:

```
.col {
  @include flex(1);
  display: block;
  padding: ($grid-padding-width / 2);
  width: 100%;
}
```

I delete the `display:block;` and `width: 100%;` also works well.
So, why ionic put these properties here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The reason**

There is a chance that other classes or styles override your situation, but not all situations. That causes your use-case to work fine, but does not mean every use-case works fine.

In this case, it is actually a back-up for the `flex` rules. `Flexbox` is not supported by older browsers, and the `display: block;` and `width:100%;` are used as fallback rules for those browsers.

---

**Reproduce**

Navigate to [ionic grid](http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#grid-even)

On the right side of the screen, you have a phone example with `col` elements.

Inspect one of those `col` elements

Disable the `flex` classes. These are the only active classes then:

```
display: block;
padding: 5px;
width: 100%;
```

You will see that it appears nothing changes.

Comment: I would suggest an edit. I think 'fallback' is a more appropriate term than 'hacks', wouldn't you agree, as 'hacks' would seem to refer to or be confused with css hacks such prepended characters that only legacy browsers recognise such as the * or \9.

Comment: @cjross Agreed and updated. Next time, you could actually click the 'edit' button and edit the question. That way you get 2 rep.